# How to use __get__() on global variable?

Tags: python

I want to be able to set a variable to a wrapper when it is passed to a track function. It might be easier to understand with some code. This is what I want to do:

```py
variables = []

def track(variable):
    variables.append(variable)
    return Wrapper(variable)

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.variable

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.variable = value


num = 42
track(num)

print(num)
# 42

num = 5
print(num)
# 5
```

I don't want to print the wrapper, but the variable the wrapper contains. I get `<__main__.Wrapper object at 0x02F208D0>`, which I don't want.

Comment: Are you making an instance of `Wrapper`? Show us how you are using it.

Comment: Yes, when the track function is called it returns a Wrapper instance

Comment: I don't think you can use the descriptor protocol to change the behavior of ordinary assignment if the left hand side doesn't have any attribute access. You can't make `num = 5` do anything other than assign the integer value `5` to `num`

Comment: In your example, `track` returns `None` and it's inner function also returns `None`.

Comment: Is there any workaround? @Kevin

Comment: Sorry wwii, the original code returned a Wrapper, I edited the question

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just make the variable a Wrapper class so I can control what values it is assigned to

Comment: @cppcppcpp you are fundamentally misunderstand what variables *are*. Your list is called `variables`, but there *are no variables in your list*. Your list contains *objects*. Variables are *names* that *refer to objects*. You cannot control how assignment works, you can merely control how you interact with an object.

Comment: When you do `num = 2` it will not invoke `Wrapper.__get__` it will just throw the reference away and create another

Comment: You can achieve that with objects, by using properties, no need to go down to descriptors

Comment: @geckos um, `property` **is** a descriptor. And there is nothing wrong with using descriptors to control access to an attribute, that is what they are for.

Comment: Or overloading the `<<=` operator or something like that

Comment: `property` is **a** descriptor, so properties are abstraction over descriptors, they are easier to work and type

Comment: if you add `def __repr__(self): return repr(self.variable)` to Wrapper it will print what you want, but still it will not track against assignments

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you cannot change the meaning of literal assignment: `num = 5` will always assign the `int` `5` to a *new* name `num`, new in the sense that it does not matter whether the name `num` exists beforehand (in that case it is simply overwritten with no regard for its old content).

To add a custom string representation to `Wrapper`, just add the method

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.variable)
```

after which

```
num = 42
num = track(num)
print(num)
```

will indeed print `42` instead of something like `<__main__.Wrapper object at 0x02F208D0>`.